# Exception occurred when creating MZContentProviderUpload for provider. (1004)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I tried to upload the app build using Xcode but I got this error **"no accounts with itunes connect access"** I then tried to upload the IPA using application loader and I got this error **"Exception occurred when creating MZContentProviderUpload for provider. (1004)"**

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It seems like a temporary issue with apple. Trying few times to send worked and the upload was successful.

Comment: Same here. Additionally now they say _"We are currently experiencing processing issues. Build processing may be delayed._, so it kind of confirms it's at Apple side.

Comment: Yes. It seems to be an apple issue. Uploading from xcode is still faulty for some reason.

Comment: oof appreciate this information. thank goodness it's not a problem with my app :)

Answer (score 6):

For me just log out on Web iTunesConect / AppsoreConnect portal.

Quit Xcode (if Possible restart) and then upload the build.

If you close all the other app and upload build in sylo makes a job easy.

Also using the "Application Loader" is a Good Solution!

Comment: I think this is the real issue, not the selected one. Thanks, it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue. In my case I tried to login another Apple Developer account via Safari. I solved this by doing:

Logout the account from Xcode and login again. It works successfully for me. No need to generate build again.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error many times during 3 hours. Sometimes along with other errors with it.

What helped: re-loginning to`itunesconnect` and restarting Mac after that. Build has uploaded from 1st attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I log in a different account in another app(iBook log in as my personal account).
I solved this by re-login in xCode, re-archive the app, upload again.

Answer (score 0):

A restart of macOS fixed this issue for me. Restarting Xcode and signing out of iTunes Connect didn't help. Also, no need to rebuild again. After the restart the previous build uploaded just fine on the first attempt.