# Xcode 9.3 build upload Error: Exception occurred when creating MZContentProviderUpload for provider. (1004)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode9.3

Error in upload builds on TestFlight/AppStore. I am using Xcode 9.3 and error throws:

An error occurred saving your changes to the Apple database. Exception occurred when creating MZContentProviderUpload for provider. (1004) An unknown error occurred.

Anyone help me why I am getting this error?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Looks like something's up with Apple's servers. I am getting the same error so this confirms that. I was able to upload my app earlier today but from the past one hour, it's not working.

UPDATE: Although the upload went through for me, the app is still stuck under processing. Looks like their servers are still acting up.

UPDATE 2: After waiting for an hour and a half, the app finally got processed.

Comment: Happening to me, too.

Comment: I was able to upload it now. It's under processing. Should work now I think

Comment: I am still unable to upload.

Comment: Did you try with application loader? You don't need to archive again and again, just keep trying. I didn't close or re-login anything. Eventually it worked for me.

Comment: My Xcode upload failed 3 times in a row with this error. 4th one worked. Keep trying…

Comment: @Mr.Dev yes tried with Application Loader. But same error.

Answer (score 3):

This is the temporary issue with Apple Server. Please wait for an hour and try again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351487/exception-occurred-when-creating-mzcontentproviderupload-for-provider-1004/52226792#52226792). I was getting this error many times during 3 hours. Sometimes along with other errors with it.

What helped: re-loginning to`itunesconnect` and restarting Mac after that. Build has uploaded from 1st attempt.

Comment: Think this was just a coincidence. Didn't not work for me.